# How to implement time picker spinner in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, time

I am trying to implement `timePicker` in spinner form in flutter.

Here is the time picker image which I want to implement:

[image]

Comment: I have need same time picker , if you have complete success of this time picker pleae let me know, which plugin you have to use

Comment: Hii, use flutter_time_picker_spinner: ^2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flutter_time_picker_spinner: ^2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_time_picker_spinner/example)

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 100
        ),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
//            hourMinute12H(),
            hourMinute15Interval(),
//            hourMinuteSecond(),
//            hourMinute12HCustomStyle(),
            new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 50
              ),
              child: new Text(
                _dateTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + ':' +
                    _dateTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + ':' +
                    _dateTime.second.toString().padLeft(2, '0'),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }


  /// SAMPLE
  Widget hourMinute12H(){
    return new TimePickerSpinner(
      is24HourMode: false,
      onTimeChange: (time) {
        setState(() {
          _dateTime = time;
        });
      },
    );
  }
  Widget hourMinuteSecond(){
    return new TimePickerSpinner(
      isShowSeconds: true,
      onTimeChange: (time) {
        setState(() {
          _dateTime = time;
        });
      },
    );
  }
  Widget hourMinute15Interval(){
    return new TimePickerSpinner(
      spacing: 40,
      minutesInterval: 15,
      onTimeChange: (time) {
        setState(() {
          _dateTime = time;
        });
      },
    );
  }
  Widget hourMinute12HCustomStyle(){
    return new TimePickerSpinner(
      is24HourMode: false,
      normalTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 24,
        color: Colors.deepOrange
      ),
      highlightedTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 24,
        color: Colors.yellow
      ),
      spacing: 50,
      itemHeight: 80,
      isForce2Digits: true,
      minutesInterval: 15,
      onTimeChange: (time) {
        setState(() {
          _dateTime = time;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ..I have attached one image with question can we get exactly the same time picker in flutter ?

Comment: You can checkout this plugin. It will tell you everything regarding what you want to implement.

Comment: I am already using this plugin , but I am not able to understand that how to get time is this format (4:30 PM) ..

Comment: Your answer is really helpful for me ..

Answer (score 0):

```
`
void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: TimePicker()));
}

class TimePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimePicker({super.key});

  @override
  State<TimePicker> createState() => _TimePickerState();
}

class _TimePickerState extends State<TimePicker> {
  DateTime time = DateTime(2016, 5, 10, 22, 35);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 220,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                      initialDateTime: time,
                      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
                      use24hFormat: true,
                      // This is called when the user changes the time.
                      onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
                        setState(() => time = newTime);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                });
          },
          child: const Text("Pick time"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```